General question about exact matching on variable/s
I haven't used matching a lot but have certainly read many papers (some quite old and obviously before propensity scores were used much) that have talked about 1:1 matching on age, sex, etc variables across exposure groups.
I presume these kinds of descriptions still relate to frequency matching - similar to what is being done with propensity scores - i.e. making the covariate distributions about equal across exposure groups.
[a small digression - this is different to individual? matching (i.e. matched-pairs) where each paired cluster needs to be specifically accounted for using something like conditional logistic regression (not sure I really understand how this is different and when it might be needed)].
I am wondering when exact matching methods (without the use of ps scores) are mentioned in a paper sans much detail, what is the minimum robust analysis that should have been done? Should the variables being matched on still be included in the regression model and should a cluster-robust error be specified.
I guess this is less relevant nowadays as it would be more common to match on propensity scores than the variables directly, and reading the matchit vignette on estimating treatment effects, suggests to do both of the above with ps scores.

Yes, these descriptions usually refer to frequency matching. There often isn't any clustering involved; that is, when you recruit a case you also recruit a control of the same age and sex, but the control is not expected to be similar to the case in any other respect.  The control might well be drawn randomly from a database of potential controls conditional on age and sex, for example (that's how we did it).  The age matching might well not be 'exact' -- nearest year is possible, but five-year bands or wider did exist.
This matching differs importantly from propensity score matching in that the goal is not to control confounding via matching but rather to get the case and control distributions to overlap enough that confounding can be controlled via regression.
That is, if you take cases of stroke and controls that are not matched for age, there will be essentially no overlap in the age distributions. If you then adjust for age by regression, there will be little variation in the outcome for most ages: at the low ages everyone will be a control, at the high ages everyone will be a case. The main goal of frequency matching was to avoid this situation.
Standard practice was to use at least the matching variables as adjustment variables in any analysis. If you don't, and if the matching variables have an effect, test statistics for other variables are stochastically smaller than their nominal distributions.
One might use more detail in analysis than in matching; for example, if age was matched in 5-year bands one might model age continuously in the analysis.  There would also be other adjustment variables not used in the matching, either because they were not available before sampling or because they were already thought to have overlapping distributions between cases and controls [1]
Clustering was not needed and not used, because the matched controls were not expected to be similar to the cases over and above the matching variables.  If the matching strata ended up small, conditional logistic regression would have been used.
[1] you might think matching on sex was often unnecessary, and you might well be right, but epidemiologists match on sex by spinal reflex.

Thank you - that is really helpful. So is it fair to say that if you want to go down a matching path these days, matching on propensity scores is an all-round better alternative than directly matching on variables? i.e. is there any reason to do the latter anymore?

I don't know enough about matching to be confident on this. There might be other reasons for matching on individual variables.

@LucaS note that Thomas's great answer is describing matching for case-control studies, whereas PS matching is primarily used for cohort studies. The purpose and goals of matching are quite different between these two designs, and it is important not to confuse them.
